# multi_gpu_model changing layer names (Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use the same code to build a convolutional neural network on two different computers, the model names and summary are totally different. The only difference is that for one I use multi_gpu_model and train with gpus, but on the other I don't. Anybody know why this is happening? Is there a simpler work around? This throws off my model analysis code because the layers are in a different order. I'm using Keras 2.3.1 and TensorFlow 1.15.4 to maintain compatibility

Here is my code to build the CNN

```
def build_cnn(input_dim, output_dim, other_input_dim, C1_K, C1_S, C2_K, C2_S, C3_K, C3_S, stride_length, num_dense_nodes, dropout, activation, learning_rate, output_activation='linear'):
    
    input_1 = keras.Input(shape=(input_dim, 1), name='Spectral_input')
    conv_1 = Conv1D(C1_K, (C1_S), strides=stride_length, padding="same", activation=activation, name='conv_1')(input_1)
    
    conv_2 = Conv1D(C2_K, (C2_S), strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation, name='conv_2')(conv_1)
    
    conv_3 = Conv1D(C3_K, (C3_S), strides=1, padding="same", activation=activation, name='conv_3')(conv_2)


    conv_output = Flatten()(conv_3)
    
    input_2 = keras.Input(shape=(other_input_dim, ), name='Instrument_input')

    merged = concatenate(axis=1, inputs=[conv_output, input_2])
    
    dense_1 = Dense(num_dense_nodes, activation=activation)(merged)
    dense_1 = Dropout(dropout)(dense_1)

    dense_2= Dense(num_dense_nodes, activation=activation)(dense_1)
    dense_2= Dropout(dropout)(dense_2)

    dense_3 = Dense(int(num_dense_nodes), activation=activation)(dense_2)
    dense_3 = Dropout(dropout)(dense_3)

    dense_4 = Dense(int(num_dense_nodes), activation=activation)(dense_3)
    dense_4 = Dropout(dropout)(dense_4)

    outputs = Dense(output_dim, activation=output_activation)(dense_4)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=outputs, name="Raman_CNN")
    
    try:
        model = multi_gpu_model(model)
    except:
        pass

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizers.Adadelta(lr=learning_rate))
    
    return model
```

and here are the two model summaries
GPU model:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Spectral_input (InputLayer)     (None, 3276, 1)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Instrument_input (InputLayer)   (None, 6)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (None, 3276, 1)      0           Spectral_input[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)               (None, 6)            0           Instrument_input[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 3276, 1)      0           Spectral_input[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 6)            0           Instrument_input[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Raman_CNN (Model)               (None, 7)            900805      lambda_1[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_2[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_3[0][0]                   
                                                                 lambda_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Concatenate)           (None, 7)            0           Raman_CNN[1][0]                  
                                                                 Raman_CNN[2][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 900,805
Trainable params: 900,805
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

CPU model:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Spectral_input (InputLayer)     (None, 3276, 1)      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_1 (Conv1D)                 (None, 656, 10)      170         Spectral_input[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_2 (Conv1D)                 (None, 656, 10)      6410        conv_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv_3 (Conv1D)                 (None, 656, 10)      3210        conv_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)             (None, 6560)         0           conv_3[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Instrument_input (InputLayer)   (None, 6)            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 6566)         0           flatten_2[0][0]                  
                                                                 Instrument_input[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          840576      concatenate_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 128)          0           dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          16512       dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 128)          0           dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          16512       dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 128)          0           dense_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 128)          16512       dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 128)          0           dense_7[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)                 (None, 7)            903         dropout_6[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 900,805
Trainable params: 900,805
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

standalone code:

```
parameters = {'num_dense_nodes' : 128, 
              'dropout': 0.01, 
              # 'Resolution_factor':1 , 
              'C1_K': 4, #Number of kernelsfor first layer
              'C1_S': 16, #Width of the kernals for the first layer
              'C2_K': 4, #Number of kernelsfor second layer
              'C2_S': 32, #Width of the kernals for the second layer
              'C3_K': 4, #Number of kernelsfor third layer
              'C3_S': 64, #Width of the kernals for the third layer
              'stride_length': 5, 
              'activation': 'relu',
              'output_activation':'linear',
              'learning_rate':.1}


parameters['input_dim'] = 3276
parameters['output_dim'] = 7
parameters['other_input_dim'] = 6

model = build_cnn(**parameters)

model.summary()
```

Comment: Are you using `4` GPU's ? Can you share executable code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just using two gpus. Added an executable code for you. For some extra info my computer with GPUs is linux based and my laptop without GPUs uses Windows 10